# mongodb strange logfile entries

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I'm running mongodb server 2.4.5 on Ubuntu 12.04.1. My application writes to the DB via Morphia Layer (0.104) and mongo-java-driver (2.12-rc2). Things work nice. However in the /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log there are entries like:

Fri Mar 28 07:45:12.614 [conn3621] update messdatenDB.meterdata query: { _id: "53351a789932d0c43be306c3" } update: { _id: "53351a789932d0c43be306c3", datum: 1395989112296, name: "010034070000", deviceType: "SGH", deviceID: "DC006487", mandantID: "520dee1299322f8346c57fd6", value: 0.7000000000000001, unit: "V", version: 1 } idhack:1 nupdated:1 upsert:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:39 318ms
F

I get these entries just for this db/collection. Sometimes every few minutes, sometimes there is a gap for some hours.

The collection 'messdatenDB.meterdata' is regularly written to with new data objects - there is never an update like the logfile says. Does that mean, that double id's are created? Can anyone give me a hint, what the logfile entry might tell? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: James's answer below is right about the slow queries bit.  As for why you're seeing _id in the update, we'd have to see some code.

Comment: OK the code is pretty easy:
`MeterDataEntity mvalue = new MeterDataEntity();`
... fill mvalue ...
`EntityDAO<MeterDataEntity> dao = MongoDBServer.getInstance().getDaoFactory().map(MeterDataEntity.class, null);
dao.save(mvalue);`
_MeterDataEntity_ is a POJO with annotations for morphia and an unique id of type _ObjectId_.
_EntityDAO_ is derived from _BasicDAO_ from the morphia classes.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB will write an entry to the log file when an operation takes longer than your [slowMS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#slowms) threshold - which defaults to 100ms. In this case your operation took 318ms. So the reason you see this is really just due to to length of time it took for this update to complete. You can tune this threshold and optionally log slow operations to a profiling collection via the [database profiler](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/).

As for **_id** it is strange that that it is being included as part of the **update** clause. _id by definition is immutable and cannot be changed. In this case the update is trying to set the _id to its existing value and results in a no-op. If the update tried to change the value of _id it would fail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes indeed that's what astonished me too: The underlying morphia must do some trick here to generate an update query with 'id' field included. For I always put in new instances of collection items, that's for sure. Could that also be the cause for a relatively slow operation? As for now, I will not change the slowMS parameter, but will try to modify the insert operation. I'll post any changes.

Comment: An upsert made with _id as the query shouldn't be much slower than an insert. It looks like the latest Morphia release is 0.107 it may be worth upgrading to see if the _id behavior changes. To troubleshoot performance a good first step is to setup MMS (http://mms.mongodb.com/) if you haven't already. The charts provided can provide clues to where a bottleneck may lie.

Comment: Where did you find the 0.107 Version of Morphia? I downloaded from [link]http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/morphia/morphia/ but there the latest Version is still 0.104. Thanks for posting.

Comment: as of 0.105 it moved under org.mongodb.morphia.  Details are on the mailing list and the github page (github.com/mongodb/morphia)